# Generic properties of Blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

How do I have parameters of a component accepted different types of data

I have a blazer component (usage below) that I will bind to several fields
It

- lets a user enter a value in a bunch of different units (passed in via UnitsInfo)
- does some range checking and confirmation
- outputs a normalized value along with what was entered (eg my air pressure might take kPa/mmHg/PSI and convert to mmHg for the normalized value)

There are 2 properties EnteredValue NormalisedValue that I have specified as decimal but would like to be able to bind to integer values as well
I have tried using @typeparam and setting the types as iNumber but with no luck

```
<NumberWithUnits_Decimal  
  @bind-DisplayNumber="LocVM.AirPressureEnteredValue_String"
  @bind-EnteredValue="LocVM.AirPressureEnteredValue"
  @bind-EnteredUnit="LocVM.AirPressureEnteredUnit" 
  @bind-NormalisedValue="LocVM.AirPressureAsMmHg"
  @bind-EntredFullString="LocVM.AirPressureConcat"
  @bind-AmberRange_ConfrimChk="LocVM.AirPressureEnteredValue_Confirmed"
  NaName="Not Applicable"  NaAllowed="true" 
  UnitsInfo="@UnitListForField("AirPressure")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to a getter/setter and then add logic to the setter to update whatever values you'd like.  Something like:

```
private int _enteredValueInt;
private decimal _enteredValue;
public decimal EnteredValue {
    get { return (_enteredValue); }
    set {
        _enteredValue = value;
        _enteredValueInt = (int)_enteredValue; // Or explicitly do rounding as needed
    }
}
```